# JTA in jboss 5 and persist race

Tags: java, jboss, jta

I've ran into a weird JTA scenarion in jboss 5.1.0.GA. I've got a service class with two methods `removeEntity()` and `findEntityByField()` - the names reflect the action.

When I call `removeEntity()` and immediately afterwards run `findEntityByField()` with a field argument matching the removed entity - it is still found in db. This only happens when `removeEntity()` use `EntityManager.remove()`, if I use a delete (named) query instead it works as expected (?!).

Looking at the database it is removed no matter which implementation I've used.

Implementation of "problematic" `removeEntity()`:

```
public void removeEntity(long id) {
  EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  MyEntity myEntity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);
  entityManager.remove(myEntity);
  entityManager.close();
}
```

Implementation of working `removeEntity()`:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "deleteById", query = "delete MyEntity where id = :id")

public void removeEntity(long id) {
  EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("deleteById");
  query.setParameter("id", id);
  query.executeUpdate();
  entityManager.close();
}
```

Implementation of `findEntityByField()`:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findByField", query = "from MyEntity where field = :field"),

public MyEntity findEntityByField(String field) {
  EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByField");
  query.setParameter("field", field);
  MyEntity myEntity = query.getSingleResult();
  entityManager.close();
  return myEntity;
}
```

Could be worth to mention that I have a unit test for this scenarion which doesn't fail. But that's not identical to the JTA case as it's `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` transaction is manually/explicitly committed.

I can accept working with named queries to delete entites but I would really like to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void removeEntity(long id) {
  EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  MyEntity myEntity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);
  entityManager.remove(myEntity);
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
  entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: This is what my (JPA) unit test does, while I guess that would work I'm not sure that's the best way to work? My hopes are that leaving the transcation maangement to the container it allows it to become more efficient in both caching and committing data.

Comment: (and also, even if it works, my main concern is to understand why .remove() doesn't work)